# only getting 52khs on Litecoin mining with a Nvidia GTX670

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, mining-software, gpu

I want to give mining a try with the current video card i have. I know its not good for mining but its a start. I use cgminer and link it with WeMineLTC. For some reason I only get 52 KHash/s. I saw my GPU is at 100% and it isn't overclocked. What should be the reason I only get this low hash per second? I saw on [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) page it should be around 112 000 KHash/s.

This is my bat file

```
cgminer.exe --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3335 -u workIt -p totallymypsw -I 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud instead use cudaminer for this. I use the same card and I have a mining rate of 150khash.

The reason why you get a low mining rate is because Nvidia cards use CUDA cores to do most of their calculation and most of the miners do not use them since the best graphic cards for mining are AMD cards (and they do not have CUDA cores).

I dont know where you saw that 112 000 Khash/s (mostly because you forgot to give the link) but I doubt that a single card could do that with litecoins (but its possible with Bitcoins).

Comment: I added the page. So the Hash rate of bitcoins is different than litecoins? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yeah, your link is for Bitcoin mining, refer to this page for Litecoin mining: https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison

Comment: Actually didn't know what hash per second was. I thought it was a standard value like Mhz but it more like complete calculations per second. Thanks for your help!